# Insert a DatePicker

Tags: google-apps-script

I work around this script:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial?hl=it

In this code part.

```
 var textApptDate = app.createTextBox();
    // Text entered in the text box is passed in to apptDate
  textApptDate.setName('apptDate');
  var day = new Date();
  day.setDate(day.getDate()+1);
  textApptDate.setText(Utilities.formatDate(day, "PDT", "MM/dd/yyyy"));
  grid.setWidget(0, 0, app.createLabel('Appointment Date:'));
  grid.setWidget(0, 1, textApptDate);
```

I  change the code for insert a DatePicker

```
 var day = new Date();
   day.setDate(day.getDate()+1); 
   var textApptDate = app.createDateBox().setName('apptDate').setValue(day);
 var handler = app.createServerHandler('change');
   handler.addCallbackElement(textApptDate).;
```

DataPicker work fine but the script don't work fine.

where is the error?

thank you for help me.

raffaele

Answer (score 0):

In the original script the value of the date in the handler function ( `var apptDate = e.parameter.apptDate;`
 ) is a string. The manipulations that follow in the code convert that string into a date object.

When you replace the widget by a dateBox the value of `var appDate` in the handler is not a string anymore, it is already a date object.  So the following string manipulations won't work.

You have 2 possibilities  :

1. convert this date object to a string and keep the code as it is (but this is a bit silly in my opinion because it's a kind of 'undo/redo')
2. Take that difference into account and go directly to the hour setting using the date object as starting value (which will be much more efficient and 'elegant').